# Interesting Mac OS X error

Tags: macos, kernel, error

Has anyone ever seen an error like the one pictured below on Mac OS X? What is it? The system is 10.6.6. I'm quite experienced in OS X but I've never seen such a thing. I was booting in verbose modem, and it looks like the verbose mode came "through".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a kernel panic in Verbose mode.

Comment: Have you installed anything recently, especially new hardware/drivers or system-level software (kexts, etc.)?

Comment: I did but 'm suspecting it was the Blizzard updater. BTW i know it's a kernel panic but i've never seen this "verbose-mode-overlay"

Comment: When you have verbose mode enabled you get verbose kernel panics too instead of the "you must restart your computer" screen.  (Older versions of Mac OS X always panicked this way.) Certainly, at the least you should contact Rogue Amoeba.

Answer (score 4):

It's an old-style kernel panic report.  When the kernel crashes, there's no way to log what happened ('cause logging requires a working filesystem, which is part of the kernel...), so OS X used to dump the crash info onto the screen buffer.

In OS X v10.2, they switched to a system where it stores the crash info into PRAM, and displays a message that "You need to restart your computer. Hold the Power button for several seconds or press the Restart button." in 4 languages.  After rebooting, the info is transferred from PRAM to a normal log file.

...but sometimes, for some reason, the old-style panic report still shows up under newer versions of OS X.  I haven't seen this happen in a while, but apparently it's still possible under 10.6.6.  I have no idea what causes it to revert to the old-style report (maybe verbose mode?).

See [Apple's KB article #HT1392](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1392) for more details, and examples of the different panic styles.

EDIT: It occurs to me that it might've both written the crash info to the screen, *and* to PRAM and hence the log files.  Check in /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and see if there's a matching panic report.

Comment: Is there a layman way of reading the cause of a kernel panic? Is it safe to share your logs in /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports? Is there any sensitive/private information contained in them?

Comment: @HandyRandy: the panic logs aren't going to be terribly readable to anyone other than a kernel programmer -- in this case, you can tell that the kernel extension "com.rogueamoeba.hermes" was involved (and since the current process was kextd, which loads & unloads kernel extensions, hermes may've either just been loaded or some other extension that conflicts with it just loaded).  The logs should generally be safe to share, although it's there's a very small probability something sensitive will happen to be in a register or the call stack when it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a kernel panic. Looks like a kernel extension with the bundle identifier "com.rogueamoeba.hermes" (Airfoil?) crashed.